# Pandas Multi-Index aggregations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi indexed pandas dataframe like -

```
   a             b           c
c1   c2      c1    c2     c1   c2   
9   10.0     162  165     16  15.0
```

I want to create another column which would contain sum of c1 columns and c2 columns for that row like -

```
   a             b           c          total
c1   c2      c1    c2     c1   c2      c1   c2
9   10.0     162  165     16  15.0     187  190
```

How to I achieve the same considering there can be n number of level 1 columns (a,b,c,d...) and n number of level 2 columns (c1,c2,c3,c4...)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please the constructor of your dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. sum using `level=1` and `axis=1`
2. Convert the result to multiindex
3. use `pd.concat` to join the result with your original df.

```
df1 = df.sum(level=1, axis=1)
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['total'], df1.columns])
df = pd.concat([df, df1], 1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   a          b        c        total       
  c1    c2   c1   c2  c1    c2     c1     c2
0  9  10.0  162  165  16  15.0  187.0  190.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `stack` to reshape then `assign` the `total` column by summing along the columns axis, then `unstack` to reshape back

```
s = df.stack()
s.assign(total=s.sum(1)).unstack()
```

---

```
     a          b          c        total       
    c1    c2   c1   c2    c1    c2     c1     c2
0  9.0  10.0  162  165  16.0  15.0  187.0  190.0
```